# How to join as a string a property of a class?

Tags: c#, string, list

"I have a List of objects with a property "CustomizationName".

I want to join by a comma the values of that property, i.e.; something like this:

```
List<MyClass> myclasslist = new List<MyClass>();
myclasslist.Add(new MyClass { CustomizationName = "foo"; });
myclasslist.Add(new MyClass { CustomizationName = "bar"; });
string foo = myclasslist.Join(",", x => x.CustomizationName);
Console.WriteLine(foo); // outputs 'foo,bar'
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
string foo = String.Join(",", myClasslist.Select(m => m.CustomizationName).ToArray());
```

If you want, you can turn this into an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, string> func)
    {
        return ToDelimitedString(source,",",func);
    }

    public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string delimiter, Func<T, string> func)
    {
        return String.Join(delimiter, source.Select(func).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string StringProp { get; set; }
}
```

.....

```
        var list = new List<MyClass>();
        list.Add(new MyClass { StringProp = "Foo" });
        list.Add(new MyClass { StringProp = "Bar" });
        list.Add(new MyClass { StringProp = "Baz" });

        string joined = list.ToDelimitedString(m => m.StringProp);
        Console.WriteLine(joined);
```

Comment: Great answer but you don't need the .ToArray() part.

Comment: @DavidThielen This answer is from '09, 5 years ago, before .Net 4.0 was out. In older versions of .Net, you couldn't pass an IEnumerable to String.join, it had to be an array.

Comment: needs using System.Linq (i know it may be obvious, but i had to look for it)