# Array of Objects to String - ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Trying to convert Array of Objects to String using C#. Able to achieve the same using LINQ, however trying to make use of reusable functions which would accept array of Objects and return back string. Understand that generics must be used but it's been hard time understanding it. Thanks in advance!

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void Main() {
    Root root = new Root();
    List<A> obj = new List<A>();
    obj.Add(new A() { Code = "WAY"});
    obj.Add(new A() { Code = "DOWN"});
    obj.Add(new A() { Code = "WE"});
    obj.Add(new A() { Code = "GO"});
    root.A = obj;

   string _Result = string.Join("-", root.A.Where(x => x.Code != "").Select(p => p.Code.ToString()).ToArray());
   Console.WriteLine(_Result);  //Expected OP: WAY-DOWN-WE-GO
      
   Console.WriteLine(Utility.ToArray(root.A)); //System.Collections.Generic.List`1[A]
  }
    
//Trying for much simpler Generic function here.
    public class Utility{
    public static string ToArray(IList<Object> obj){
        foreach(var v in obj){
           //generic function..
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

```
                    
 public class Root
{
    public List<A> A { get; set; }
    public List<B> B { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Mode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You don't actually ask a question, do you? What are you trying to achieve, what did you try, what is the problem,  What error are you getting... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a system that works without having to have your classes implement an interface (for objects you didn't create, for example), it's possible to use a `Func<T, object>` to select a specific property/field:

```cs
// IEnumerable is more generic over "lists" (sets, maps, etc)
//                                   \/
public static string ToArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> obj, Func<T, object> func) {
    return string.Join('-', obj.Select(func));
}
```

Usage example:

```cs
List<A> aObjects = new();
//add aObjects
List<B> bObjects = new();
//add bObjects

Console.WriteLine(Utilities.ToArray(aObjects, a => a.Code));
Console.WriteLine(Utilities.ToArray(bObjects, b => b.Mode));
```

Reference: [How to join as a string a property of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978505/how-to-join-as-a-string-a-property-of-a-class)

Comment: And It worked like a charm. Woweeee  Kazaweee...Thanks mate.